# Why log4net doesn't log nhibernate information

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, logging, web-config, log4net

My Visual Studio Solution contains:

1. [DLL] Sol.DataAccess (NHibernate sessionManager)
2. [DLL] Sol.Core (Models and Repository)
3. [MVC] Sol.WebMvc (Controler, View)

All my application contains are (nhibernate.dll [v3.0] and log4net.dll[v1.2.10])

I have 3 configs:

web.config:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
         <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net, Version=1.2.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1b44e1d426115821" requirePermission="false" />
         <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

nhibernate.config:

```
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2" >
  <session-factory name="...">
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">...</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">10</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="generate_statistics">true</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect</property>
    <property name="use_outer_join">true</property>
    <property name="max_fetch_depth">2</property>
    <property name="command_timeout">60</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">25</property>
    <property name="query.substitutions">true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'</property>
    <property name="proxyfactory.factory_class">NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">web</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2.SysCacheProvider, NHibernate.Caches.SysCache2</property>
    <mapping assembly="..."/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and log4net.config:

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
    <!--for release-->
    <!--<bufferSize value="10" />-->
    <!--for debug-->
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="Data Source=xxxxx; Initial Catalog=xxxx; User Id=xxxx; Password=xxxxx; App=xxxx" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO Logs ([Application],[Host],[User],[Date],[Thread],[Level],[Operation],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@app, @hostName, @userName, @log_date, @thread, @log_level, @operation, @logger, @message, @exception)" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@app" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="xxxx" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@hostName" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{hostName}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@userName" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{userName}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@operation" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{Operation}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="2000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
  </appender>

  <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="Logs/Logs.txt"/>
    <appendToFile value="true"/>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender> 

  <appender name="Console" type="log4net.Appender.AspNetTraceAppender">
    <!--A1 uses PatternLayout-->
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <!--Print the date in ISO 8601 format-->
      <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger %ndc - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <level value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
  </root>
</log4net>
```

Global.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
       ...
        // Configuration

        #region log4net
        // log4net.config
        System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/log4net.config"));
        if (fi != null && fi.Exists)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(fi);
        }

        // web.config
        //log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        // set properti hostName
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["hostName"] = Dns.GetHostName();
        #endregion

        #region NHibernate
        //HibernatingRhinos.Profiler.Appender.NHibernate.NHibernateProfiler.Initialize();
        var factory = NHibernateSessionManager.ConfigureFromFile(Server.MapPath("~/hibernate.config"));
        #endregion
    }
```

in my test controller i have:

```
public class TestController : BaseController
    {
        [NHibernateSession]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
             Logger.Error("fake error", new Exception());
        }
     }
```

In my log file - Logs/Logs.txt:

```
2011-03-11 18:19:23,097 [8] ERROR System.Web.Mvc.Controller [(null)] - fake error
System.Exception: Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown.
```

**QUESTION:** 
Why log4net doesn't log  NHibernate information (info, debug ....)

Aren't the versions of these dlls compatible?

Comment: in TestController i have tryed to do select and save using nhibernate sessions ...

Comment: You probably don't want to publish your password on a public forum, do you?

Comment: I have try use same web.config, log4net.config, nhibernate.config, in new webForms project frome same solustion. and it work.   How can I do to work for MVC ?

Comment: This is similar to my experience with Log4Net.  It is way too easy to configure it badly, and have no clue as to why it's failing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have create an empty ASP.Net MVC3 project. and loss much time trying to fix this issue.
And I find VS2010 bug. **Visual Studio 2010 don't copy dll's in bin when you refer it in project.**

I put log4net.dll manual in my bin folder and  work fine. **(Interesting thing is that  Logger.Error("fake error") work fine without log4net.dll in bin folder ...)**

[image]

Comment: It depends on how you setup your project whether or not assemblies are being copied and/or refreshed. You should have seen an error in global.asax.cs though, where you placed the lines for configuration, because you cannot call methods of an unreferenced assembly. If you only had it configured in web.config, this is normal behavior: there's no way the compiler can know it should copy the assembly (which is why I often add a log4net statement somewhere, to force it). But: glad you got it resolved!

Answer (score 3):

First off: you speak of "log4net.config", but you don't include that anywhere. The way you configure it in `web.config`, you should actually include a section called `<log4net>` *inside*  your web.config, not as a separate file.

If you don't want it in your web.config, you can remove the log4net related sections altogether and add the following line to yur global.asax.cs:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(
      New FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/yourreleativepath/log4net.config")))
```

Also, possibly you miss the priority setting, not entirely sure this helps, but give it a try:

```
<root>
  <priority value="DEBUG"/>
  <appender-ref ref="Console"/>
  <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
  <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
</root>
```

Also, to finetune (because you'll get *a lot* messages), use something like this:

```
<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>

<logger name="NHibernate">
    <level value="WARN"/>
</logger>
```

On nhibernate.info you'll [find a full example](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate).

Comment: 1. in my Global.asax.cs i have :           // log4net.config
             System.IO.FileInfo fi = new     System.IO.FileInfo(Server.MapPath("~/log4net.config"));
        if (fi != null && fi.Exists)
        {
            // Code that runs on application startup
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(fi);
        }   2.      <priority value="DEBUG"/> --- i have try -> don't work.   3.   "to finetune" ->  thanks I know about this ... but I want first get the information.

Comment: @Artiom: Use breakpoints to check whether log4net is indeed loaded correctly. If that doesn't help, enable Log4net logging itself, see [here under "How do I enable log4net internal debugging?"](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html). Finally, you may still want to try to set `<logger name="NHibernate">`. It should work without it, but hey, why not just try it with?